# Count values in a table taken from a list in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, concatenation

I Have one list that is instantiated by the following:

```
SELECT 
chklRefTo
FROM CSART.DBO.tblMaintenance
```

and returns the following:

```
chklRefTo
----------
SRH
STI
GP/Walk-in
ED/UCC
Other
```

and another column of values

```
Ref to
-------
STI
STI,GP/Walk-in,ED/UCC
GP/Walk-in,ED/UCC
SRH,STI,ED/UCC
STI,Other
```

That is instantiated by this:

```
SELECT
ReferredTo AS "Reason Not Admitted"
FROM CSART.DBO.tblPhoneConsult
WHERE ReferredTo != '' AND ReferredTo IS NOT NULL
```

For each value in the first list, I need a count of the number of times each value appears in the second list. Ideally, the result of the query would look something like the below:

```
Ref    Num
-----------
STI  | 3
SRH  | 1
Other| 1
```

I haven't been having much luck trying to work through this problem so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server:

```
SELECT    chklRefTo Ref,
          COUNT(ReferredTo) Num
FROM      tblMaintenance
LEFT JOIN tblPhoneConsult
       ON ',' + ReferredTo + ',' LIKE '%,' + chklRefTo + ',%'
GROUP BY  chklRefTo
ORDER BY  2 DESC
```

By adding the commas in the `JOIN` expression you ensure that a sub-string is not considered a match. For example, it prevents a value like *"P/W"* to be considered a match with the list *"GP/Walk-in,ED/UCC"*.

The `LEFT JOIN` in combination with `COUNT(ReferredTo)` will ensure that every value of *chklRefTo* is in the result, even when the count is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
select chklRefTo as Ref, count(*) as Num
from CSART.DBO.tblMaintenance m
inner join CSART.DBO.tblPhoneConsult p on p.ReferredTo like '%' + chklRefTo + '%'
group by chklRefTo
```